# Is it possible to convert a non integer number to integer number inside preprocessor directive #define

Tags: c

Is it possible in C language, to convert a non integer number to integer number (closest greater integer) in the pre-processor directive only?

Inside the loop the the Ceil function generally does the job, but I have to define vector(constant size).

```
#define Lenght_of_box 52.5
#define Vector_size ceil(Lenght_of_box)
```

Ceil function isn't working inside the pre-processor.

Comment: What version of C are you using? Cannot you use `const` instead of `#define`?

Comment: Somebody just has commented & deleted, #define (int)(52.5+1) and it worked. Thanks

Comment: @yasir: That breaks for integral Lenght_of_box.

Comment: @yasir doing that will also return ```53``` when the real number is ```52``` or ```52.999```

Comment: @JohnSmith No issue, I need to divide the box into grids of length 1, So for 52.1 or 52.9, I need 53, also negative numbers are not my concern.  Hence (int)(52.9) works for me.

Comment: fair enough, just remember to not add the +1 if your grid has an integer length otherwise you'd have an extra space than needed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to use

```
#define f_ 55.1
#define n_ ((int)f_ + !!(f_ - (int)f_))
```

where `n_` is evaluated by the preprocessor, and is `f_` rounded up. The `!!` implements the rounding up.

Test program:

```
int main()
{
    char n[n_]; // might be a VLA, so runtime `n_` would be permitted ...
    switch (n_){
    case n_: // ...but this will not compile if `n_` is not a constant
        printf("%zu", sizeof(n)); // The value of `n_`
    }
}
```

Clearly dealing with negative numbers is not a concern.

Comment: I was just about to suggest the `!!` improvement!

Comment: @IanAbbott: Yes it reads much better that way and has fewer parentheses.

Comment: It also helps with some edge cases.

Comment: Shouldn't it rather be `((int)f_ + !!(f_ - (int)f_))`?

Comment: @Lundin: Yes I prefer that; it's much easier to explain to folk, having a conceptual conversion of 1 or 0 to a floating point doesn't feel right, and the way I wrote it had IEEE754 assumptions.

Answer (score 3):

*..."I need to divide the box into grids of length 1, So for 52.1 or 52.9, I need 53, also negative numbers are not my concern."* (from comments)

Given the corner cases you are willing to accept, this macro will work:

```
#define CEIL(x) (((x)-(int)(x)) > 0 ? (int)((x)+1) : (int)(x))
```

Tested for the following small sample size:

```
int main(void)
{
    // float num = 4.0;
    // float num = 4.999;
    float num = 4.001;
    int iNum = CEIL(num);

    printf( "This is a float to int conversion: %d\n", iNum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I didn't think that the ternary conditional operator was compile time evaluable in C. Did you test it with my fancy program?

Comment: Nice. Forgive me for my reservations on the ternary conditional and have an upvote!

Comment: It needs parentheses around the macro parameter expansions, but have an upvote anyway!

Comment: @ryyker Yes, that looks fine.